# JavaScript: How to execute an if/else statement in an onclick attribute?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting syntax errors while trying to add an if/else statement the onclick attribute. What is the syntax for this?

```
<div onclick="var element = $('#selector'); if (element.val() == 'something') { alert('hello'); } else { alert('goodbye'); } ">
    Click here 
    <input type="hidden" id="selector" value="something" />
</div>
```

...and yes, I must have this javascript in the onclick attribute (can't move this to a function).

Answer (score 5):

`.val()` is a jQuery method. You want to access the `value` property of the DOM element.

```
if (element.value == 'something') {
```

Or create a jQuery object if you have jQuery loaded:

```
if ($(element).val() == 'something') {
```

If you took that approach, you could always use a jQuery selector:

```
if ($('#selector').val() == 'something') {
```

Comment: sorry, got mixed up since I'm using jQuery. I've updated my code sample, but that's still not the problem I'm having.

Comment: @Andrew - I don't get any errors [using your code](http://jsfiddle.net/VA3pT/). What do the errors say, and which browser are you using? Also, are you sure you have jQuery loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript DOM elements do not have a `val()` function.  (Are you thinking of jQuery?)

[Change `.val()` to `.value`](http://jsfiddle.net/mzT8R/1/).

---

If you are thinking of jQuery, you can write `if ($('#selector').val() == 'something')`.

Comment: sorry, got mixed up since I'm using jQuery. I've updated my code sample, but that's still not the problem I'm having.